# iOS9 + Swift: How To Set The Body of A Post Request Using a JSON Value?

Tags: ios, swift, networking, swifty-json, self-signed

I am trying to make an HTTP Post request to a development server with self signed certificate. This is the function making the POST call:

```
func makeHTTPPostRequest(path: String, body: JSON, onCompletion: (JSON?, NSError?) -> Void) {

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: path)!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    // I am using SwiftyJSON
    do {
        request.HTTPBody = try body.rawData()
    } catch _ { }

    let configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue:NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
        var json: JSON?
        if let _data = data {
            json = JSON(data: _data)
        }
        onCompletion(json, error)
    })
    task.resume() 
}
```

When I make a POST request, the server returns me "Empty fields" error even though I have properly set the HTTPBody of the request:

[image]

PS: The route is working fine when I call it from Postman.

Comment: From you'r code block I can assume that you are trying to send JSON data. You should try to convert JSON to data using `NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject`

Comment: In SwiftyJSON, 'JSON' is a struct. I can't use this method because it expects AnyObject. However, JSON.rawData() method is returning a proper data object. I tested it by decoding the result.

Comment: Not sure what `rawData` returns, but the `request.HTTPBody` property must be a `NSData` object. In case of JSON, the data object should contain a sequence of Unicode characters (preferable UTF-8) which is your JSON - that is your serialised JSON representation. You should also set the `Content-Type` header accordingly (`application/json`).

Comment: Instead of rawData, use rawString and compose nsdata by applying encoding **request.HTTPBody = try (body.rawString() as NSString).dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)** and also set the request content-type **request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")**

Comment: Thanks both! This solved my problem. The rawData() method is working fine, only setting the Content-Type header got it working. @CouchDeveloper please make it an answer below and I'll mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `request.HTTPBody` property must be a `NSData` object. If you want to send JSON, the data object should contain a sequence of Unicode characters (preferable UTF-8) which is your serialised JSON representation.

Additionally, you should also set the `Content-Type` header accordingly to `application/json`.